# Windows batch Script - not copying to destination directory

Tags: batch-file

I want to run a batch file every two hours.  It should create a timestamped folder and create subfolders of IP addresses.  It should then map a drive to each network address and copy the contents of that folder to the folder specified in dest_dir

The script below is working except for the highlighted line:

call set val2=copy q:\faa2000\work*.log %dest_dir%

Instead of copying the files to the specified subfolder, the files are just being copied to the top level folder where the script is being executed from.

```
rem ***  create a folder for every time the script is run
Call :GetFileNameWithDateTime MyCurrentDate
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetFileNameWithDateTime <FileName>
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set "MyDate=%%x"
set "%1=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%-%MyDate:~8,2%-%MyDate:~10,2%"
goto :mkdirectory
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

rem ***  create the directory for the current execution
:mkdirectory
MkDir %MyCurrentDate%

rem ***  create an array of IP addresses
set ips[0]=10.6.30.11
set ips[1]=10.6.30.12
set ips[2]=10.6.30.13

set "x=0"

:SymLoop
if not defined ips[%x%] goto :endLoop
rem ***  map to a network drive based on array of ips addresses above

call set VAL=net use Q: \\%%ips[%x%]%%\d$ /user:sbadmin <password>
%VAL%

if exist q:\faa2000\\work (
    rem ***  create a directory for each ip address e.g. .\2022-06-23-15-41\10.6.30.11\
    call set "dest_dir=%MyCurrentDate%\%%ips[%x%]%%\"
    call mkdir %dest_dir%

    rem ***  copy the contents of a folder on the network drive to the destination directory 
    rem ***  e.g. .\2022-06-23-15-41\10.6.30.11\

    call set val2=copy q:\faa2000\work\*.log %dest_dir%  ***this is the line that isn't working***
    %val2%

)else (

    call echo %%ips[%x%]%% >> missing.txt

)

net use q: /delete
SET /a "x+=1"
GOTO :SymLoop


:endLoop
echo "Done"
```

Comment: You need double percents in that line `call set val2=... %%dest_dir%%`

Comment: interesting that you did it right with the other `call set` lines...

Comment: Also line `call mkdir %dest_dir%` should read `call mkdir %%dest_dir%%` (or even `call mkdir "%%dest_dir%%"`), and line `%val2%` should read `call %%val2%%`…